# Authentication failure when pulling package from GitLab Package Registry

Tags: maven, gitlab

I am encountering an authentication failure while trying to pull a package from the GitLab Package Registry. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

`Could not transfer metadata path/to/package/maven-metadata.xml from/to fwk-packages (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<GROUP-ID>/-/packages/maven): Authentication failed for https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/<GROUP-ID>/-/packages/maven/path/to/package/maven-metadata.xml 401 Unauthorized`

I have tried adding the repositories requesting the package into the CI job token allow list, but the issue persists. Here are some additional details:

1. I am using GitLab version 16.
2. I have verified that my user account has the necessary permissions
   to access the package.
3. I have double-checked the repository URL and ensured that it is
   correct.
4. I have confirmed that the package visibility is set correctly
   (public/private/internal).

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to pull the package successfully. Are there any additional steps or configurations I should consider to resolve this authentication failure issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem. I also double checked security and even some steps from pipeline access the repo, but others just fail with 401 for the reason described above. I believe this is some bug in gitlab.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this topic? We recently upgraded our self-managed GitLab version to 16.1, and the issue has also surfaced. However, I haven't been able to find any official reports posted regarding this issue on the GitLab repository.

Comment: try configuring the CI JOB TOKEN SCOPE : **On the left sidebar, at the top, select Search GitLab () to find your project, Select Settings > CI/CD ,Expand Token Access, Toggle Limit CI_JOB_TOKEN access to enabled, Add existing projects to the token’s access scope** : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#limit-your-projects-job-token-access